Will this power plug be alright to use?
I am doing some led lightning in my room and to power leds I bought a switching power supply which is 5V 20A 
To power it I need to buy a power plug and I am wondering if a power plug with 1.5mm squared wires is enough to not damage anything or cause fire. I live in Europe so power outlets are at 220V.
Datasheet link https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/download/259339/MEANWELL/S-100-5.html



To help get an answer can you [edit] the question to include a link to the datasheet for the power supply.

Note that the power supply is intended for use inside an enclosure that prevents access to the not-fingerproof terminals.

Roko - Hi, Where did the 1st image (which you said was what you bought) come from? It doesn't physically match the Meanwell PSU details you added later, and it looks like one of the generic PSUs available from Amazon, Ali Express etc. || To comply with the site referencing rule, please add the site name & link for the source of that 1st photo. TY

Am I the only one thing that a power supply which has 220V input right next to 5V is madness? It’s not even obvious which pin is which (as the provided datasheet does not match the first picture, as pointed out by @SamGibson). This all looks like an accident waiting to happen (in addition to the accessible connectors, the meshed enclosure, the alleged “cooling by free air convection” and the “input range selectable by switch” with no visible switch on the photos all seem like a recipe for disaster).

1.5mm squared is basically the thickest wire you see on extension cords.
It should be fine.
However, there are a few things.
Since you asked which wire is fine for the installation, you should consider if you have enough knowledge and training to do the electrical wiring and mounting of the PSU safely.
You also don't show which plug you intend to connect. You MUST use a three-prong earthed plug and connect all three wires correctly to PSU. And use a grounded outlet for the plug. In some EU countries you have grounded plugs that can be plugged into older ungrounded sockets.
You have bought a PSU intended to be put inside a metal enclosure. The wires on the screws are not safe for just connecting and left lying around for pets and kids to touch, the consequences may be deadly.
Another thing is, you should also have decent knowledge on how to terminate the wire into the PSU screw terminal. If you thought it will be fine to strip the insulation, maybe twist the copper strands and shove it under the screw, that's als an unsafe way of doing it.
You should properly terminate the copper strands with maybe a crimped ferrule that can be tightened under the screw in a way that does not become loose.
It's not recommended for common laymen to do any mains electricity work even if EU or local legislation allows it.
If you connect that PSU to mains plug, you are assumed and have the responsibility to have enough knowledge how to do it safely and according to EU and local electrical codes. If it starts a fire or electrocutes someone, the insurance company may not cover damages if they think it was not safe or done responsibly.

Thanks, I will look more into it to make it correctly and safe.

1.5mm² is massively over-sized for a power supply that won't take more than 0.96A at 220V.  If you can actually fit the cable into the plug, it will work fine.  But something smaller, such as 0.75mm² would still be more than big enough.
Make sure you use 3-core cwire, and a 3 pin plug.

It will probably be fine. 1.5mm square wires can handle much more power than this application. 5V 20A = 100VA and that does not make half an ampere in a 220V AC field. Of course there are some parameters to consider like efficiency. But even with these parameters it is so good to use.

1.5mm is good for 10A as an appliance lead and this 100W power supply will need much less than that so yeah that's fine.
Be sure to use strain relief where the appliance lead enters the enclosure that contains this power supply.
For the output, 1.5mm on each output terminals should be fine too, but I recommend using more than one pair of output terminals if you need more than 10A from the power supply.
